# Split one field into 3 fields?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I need to split the values in a field according to what they represent to be able to do a join on the data. [image: This is a cadastral polygon shapefile]

As seen above I have a ID field that needs to be split into the following:

The ID consist of 21 digits where the first 8 digits represents the **Town Code**

The next 8 digits represents the **ERF** number

The last 5 digits represents the **Portion** number.

In there a way to easily split these into their own fields as I need to join a excel sheet to Town number, ERF and Portion.

For example:

C04100030000194800000

Will be split into their own fields:

TOWN: C0410003

ERF: 00001948

PORTION: 00000

I assume that this will be done with arcpy as I have over 50 000 records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on @artwork21's excellent answer, the following is how you would accomplish the task with Python using an [UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000).

```
import arcpy

# The input feature class
fc = r'C:\temp\myfgdb.gdb\yourFC'

# Add three new fields
arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "TOWN", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "ERF", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "PORTION", "TEXT")

# Update FC with an update cursor
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["ID", "TOWN", "ERF", "PORTION"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = row[0][:8]    # "TOWN"
        row[2] = row[0][8:16]  # "ERF"
        row[3] = row[0][-5:]   # "PORTION"
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron sharing. Worked perfectly. Trying to automate most of my work so this is great.

Answer (score 13):

If the length of the ID field values is always constant I would recommend using either Field Calculator or Calculate Fields tool with python slices.

**TOWN calculation:**

```
!ID![:8]
```

**ERF calculation**

```
!ID![8:16]
```

**PORTION calculation**

```
!ID![-5:]
```

Comment: Some explanation of how Python slicing works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1394393.